# Change the look of the JSpinner arrow buttons

Tags: java, swing, button, look-and-feel, jspinner

I would like to change the look of the `JSpinner` arrow buttons so that theses buttons have no border.

Is it possible to get a reference on theses buttons to simply call a `setBorder()` on them, instead of write a spinner UI only for that purpose?

Comment: you can always scan the child components of the JSpinner and check that the component is different from `getEditor()`. The ones that are different should be the buttons (of course some UI may decide to add other or more components but it will work in most cases)

Answer (score 2):

In a subclass of `BasicSpinnerUI`, you can override the `create[Previous|Next]Button` methods and change the border on the component returned by the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is, download a source code of customLookAndFeel(like jtatto, nimbusLookandfeel,seaglass, lookandfeel,)and use only the abstract theme for JSpinners, if you cant find a code tell me I will give you the class files in that you can draw your own borders , give bgcolors,fgcolors,text rendering, button shading etc...... that class overrides many methods in BasicSpinnerUI